# Numpy condition for getting nested arrays if their max is above a threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have the following array:

```
arr = numpy.array([[.5, .5], [.9, .1], [.8, .2]])
```

I would like to get the *indices* of `arr` that contain an array whose max value is greater or equal than .9. So, for this case, the result would be `[1]` because the array with index 1 `[.9, .1]` is the only one whose max value is >= 9.

I tried:

```
>>> condition = np.max(arr) >= .9
>>> arr[condition]
array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

But, as you see, it yields the wrong answer.

Comment: Note that assigning `condition = np.max(arr) >= .9` is asking whether the maximum value of the whole array is greater than or equal to `0.9`, so is assigning `condition = True`. Using `True` as an index evaluates it in an integer context, and `int(True) == 1`, so you will always get the 2nd row of your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here. This function returns the indices of any values which meet a particular condition:

```
>>> np.where(arr >= 0.9)[0] # here we look at the whole 2D array
array([1])
```

(`np.where(arr >= 0.9)` returns a tuple of arrays of indices, one for each axis of the array. Your expected output implies that you only want the row indices (axis 0).)

If you want to take the maximum of each row first, you can use `arr.max(axis=1)`:

```
>>> np.where(arr.max(axis=1) >= 0.9)[0] # here we look at the 1D array of row maximums
array([1])
```

Comment: What's the difference from the two approaches? The first one checks each element from the nested arrays while the second it computes the max, then checks from the array of maxs?

Comment: @AndreiHorak - that's correct - I'll edit to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [18]: arr = numpy.array([[.5, .5], [.9, .1], [.8, .2]])

In [19]: numpy.argwhere(numpy.max(arr, 1) >= 0.9)
Out[19]: array([[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` along an axis to get the row max values, and then `where` to get the indexes of the biggest:

```
np.where(arr.max(axis=1)>=0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the wrong answer is because `np.max(arr)` gives you the max of the flattened array.  You want `np.max(arr, axis=1)` or, better yet, `arr.max(axis=1)`.

```
(arr.max(axis=1)>=.9).nonzero()
```

Comment: Nice approach with using `nonzero()`!